# Issue with multi stack architecture for fragments in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, out-of-memory

For my android app, I implemented a multi stack architecture. In my app, I have four tabs in bottom. From each tab, multiple fragments are created and stored in arrayList. For each tab, I am implementing a stack behavior using arrayList of fragments. But when I remove fragment from arrayList, the fragment objects still remains in memory which causes `outOfMemory error`. Is there any way to remove fragment objects from memory ?

**See the code below to remove fragments from memory :**

```
private void recycleFragment(ArrayList<Fragment> arryListRecycleFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (arryListRecycleFragment != null && arryListRecycleFragment.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < arryListRecycleFragment.size(); i++) {
                ft.remove(arryListRecycleFragment.get(i));
                /*Fragment fragment = arryListRecycleFragment.get(i);
                fragment = null;*/
            }
        }
        ft.commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        arryListRecycleFragment.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a viewpager?

Comment: @Neil yess using viewPager but in one of my fragments. Not in every fragment.

Comment: Are you loading fragments into tabs? If so please show that code

Comment: @Neil In my app, I have an activity. In that activity, I have a frameLayout where fragment is loaded and I have implemented tabs using four textViews at bottom. So actually these textviews looks like tabs.

Comment: Why aren't you using the native tabs with a viewpager? That will solve your out of memory issue.

Comment: @Neil bcoz my app's design is something like that I cannot use tabs but it should looks like tabs. That's y I am not using native tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113900/discussion-between-ruchir-and-neil).